# Make button open menu instantly

Tags: javascript, html, mobile, touchstart

I want my mobile menu to open as soon as the user touches the button. I used ontouchstart="" in both buttons to create an overlay on the content when the offcanvas menu is visible and this works as soon as the user touches either button. I would like this to work exactly the same way for the href="javascript:void(0) too, which opens the menu. Here is the website: https://londontradition.com, you can see as soon touch the menu button, the overlay becomes visible, however the menu transition will not start until you lift your finger off. Any help is appreciated thanks.

An example of where this works is here: https://www.ssense.com/

Here is the html for my menu close button:

```
<a href="javascript:void(0);" class="mobile-button visible-sm visible-xs" id="close-btn" ontouchstart="document.getElementById('content').style.cssText = 'opacity:1;';">Menu</a>
```

And here is the html for my menu open button:

```
<div class="col-sm-3 col-xs-3"><a href="javascript:void(0);" class="mobile-button" id="menu-toggle" ontouchstart="document.getElementById('content').style.cssText = 'opacity:0.1;';">Menu</a></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using `ontouchstart`, you should use `onmouseover` event. Have a look [here](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/ev_onmouseover.asp) for more information. Furthermore, you should implement a function to set it back to normal when the mouse it not hover it anymore via `onmouseout`.

This is how your code should look like:

```
<a href="javascript:void(0);" class="mobile-button visible-sm visible-xs" id="close-btn" onmouseover="document.getElementById('content').style.cssText = 'opacity:1;';" onmouseout="document.getElementById('content').style.cssText = 'opacity:0.1;';">Menu</a>
```

Comment: Hi, you may have misunderstood my question. The ontouchstart="" is the part that is working, which makes my overlay show. I would like this to work on the "href="javascript:void(0);" aswell in the same manner as the overlay.

Answer (score 0):

I have found a solution myself for anyone who is also looking for an answer.

What I did was add this to my menu open button:

```
ontouchstart="document.getElementById('sidebar').style.cssText = 'transform: translateX(0px) !important;';document.getElementById('wrapper').style.cssText = 'transform: translateX(225px) !important;';document.getElementById('top-bar').style.cssText = 'transform: translateX(225px) !important;';document.getElementById('content').style.cssText = 'opacity:0.2;';"
```

and this to my menu close button:

```
ontouchstart="document.getElementById('sidebar').style.cssText = 'transform: translateX(-225px) !important;';document.getElementById('wrapper').style.cssText = 'transform: translateX(0px) !important;';document.getElementById('top-bar').style.cssText = 'transform: translateX(0px) !important;';document.getElementById('content').style.cssText = 'opacity:1;';"
```

as soon as the user touches the button with their finger, before they even lift their finger off, the menu begins to appear.